# angstrom not working for sfmath

Tags: fonts

Latex does not display the angstrom unit using the MWE below:

```
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage[cm]{sfmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\DeclareSIUnit{\angstrom}{\mbox{\normalfont\AA}}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\AA}{%
  \leavevmode
  \vbox{\ialign{##\cr
    \hidewidth\char'27 \hidewidth\cr
    \noalign{\nointerlineskip\kern-1.0ex}
    A\cr
  }}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

random text in equation $\sim 10 \si{\angstrom}$.

random text outside equation $\sim 10 $\si{\angstrom}.
\end{document}
```

but I does not display the angstrom sign correctly. I tried removing

```
\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
```

which solves the problem but I need it for other things, so this is not an option for me. It would be great if you could help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem is, because *not* redefining `\AA` works flawlessly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[cm]{sfmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\DeclareSIUnit{\angstrom}{\mbox{\normalfont\AA}}

\begin{document}

random text in equation $\sim \qty{10}{\angstrom}$.

random text outside equation \qty{10}{\angstrom}.

\end{document}
```

Note that TS1 and `textcomp` are no longer needed and that `\qty` is better than separating the value from the unit.

[image]

Comment: Isn't the proper `\sim`: `$\qty{\sim 10}{\angstrom}$`

Comment: thanks, sorted!

Comment: In this case the ring touches the A, the redefinition puts the ring a little bit higher to have some space between the letter and the diacritic. Both variants (with and without space) seem to be used in practise, but especially for sans serif (`\sffamily\AA` instead of `\normalfont\AA`, which @AstroCoding2019 might be interested in to be consistent with the `\sfmath` package), the variant with a bit more space looks better imo.